# How to get R,G,B values of a color in Android with Java?

Tags: java, android, colors

I need to adjust the R,G,B values of some color, so I pass it to a method and try to return the adjusted value :

```
itemColor == Color.rgb(28,158,218);
```

...

```
  int adjustColor(int itemColor)
  {
     int adjustedColor;

     //How to get the R,G,B of the itemColor here ?

     adjustedColor = Color.rgb(R/2,G/2,B/2);
     return adjustedColor;
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert integer color value to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183587/convert-integer-color-value-to-rgb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you need to extract the color values from the `itemColor` variable. So use the following method:

```
int adjustColor(int itemColor)
  {
     int adjustedColor;

     int R = Color.red(itemColor);
     int B = Color.blue(itemColor);
     int G = Color.green(itemColor);

     adjustedColor = Color.rgb(R/2,G/2,B/2);
     return adjustedColor;
  }
```